# How to change multiple values in SSRS?

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

If  users enters 100, 200, 300
How can i change it to 150, 250, 350

Here is the query that i use when users enters only one value. It changes the user entered value to closest lowest number. How do i do it with multiple values?

SELECT  MAX(QUANTITY)  QUANTITY
FROM (Select DISTINCT  (QUANTITY) from #MAIN where (QUANTITY)<=@parameter)a

Answer (score 0):

You can create a second parameter in your report that is multi select.  The default values are then the result of your query and use the first parameter.  Hide this 2nd parameter, but use it in your filters.